# r - shiny : add new item to selectizInput using js

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, selectize.js

im trying to add new option to selectizInput through easybutton located in leaflet

what i get is an undefined option

Here is an example :

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

shinyApp(
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput("countries", "Country :", choices = c("Worldwide") ),
  leafletOutput("countryMap",height="500px")
),

server <- function(input, output, session){

output$countryMap <- renderLeaflet({
  leaflet() %>%
  addEasyButton(easyButton(icon = "fa-check", id = "doneMap", position = "topright", title = "Finish",
                               onClick = JS("function(btn, map){ 
                                              var $select = $('#countries').selectize();
                                              var selectize = $select[0].selectize;
                                              selectize.addOption({ value: 'selectedRegion', text: 'Selected Region' });
                                              selectize.addItem('selectedRegion');
                                            }
                                            "))) %>%
    addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldStreetMap)

 })
})
```

Comment: could you describe your desired output a bit more. Currently you are trying to add the string: 'selectedRegion' to the selectinput. Is that really what you want?

Comment: thanks for your interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem id that `data` in `addOption(data)` is an object that needs `value` and **`label`** keys, not `value` and **`text`**:

```
...,
onClick = JS("function(btn, map){ 
                  var $select = $('#countries').selectize();
                  var selectize = $select[0].selectize;
                  selectize.addOption({value: 'selectedRegion', label: 'Selected Region'});
                  selectize.addItem('selectedRegion');
              }")
```

Comment: THANKS ALOT <3 I Have wasted alot of time in this odd issue